# rails - link_to :confirm not generates data-confirm

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4.1.6 and Ruby 2.1.4. I have a `link_to`:

```
= link_to 'Delete comment', [@post, comment], :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?"
```

It generates a HTML:

```
<a confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/posts/first-post/comments/26" rel="nofollow">Delete comment</a>
```

Why it generates `confirm` rather than `data-confirm`?

My *application.js* includes:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

My *layouts/application.html.erb* includes:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specified it. Try this instead

```
= link_to 'Delete comment', [@post, comment], :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }
```

Comment: Hmm, I saw somewhere this code and it worked. Thanks, it working :)

Comment: @jazzis18, you're right. In older versions of Rails that was the right way to achieve that. Compare [3.2](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) vs [4.0](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)